# Am i using is/are correctly in these sentence?

Tags: verbs, subject-verb-agreement, compounds

1. His house and my house is close to school canteen (I used "is" instead of 'are" because we are co-owner/sharing one house)
2. His house and my house is close to school canteen (we both have two different houses but i still used "is" instead of "are" because we each have one house)
3. I know his mother and your mother are sisters( here i used "are" instead of is" because we talked about two mothers)

Comment: (2) is exactly the same as (3) - two mothers, two houses - so it should be _are_. Yes, (1) should be _is_, but most people would say _our house_ (or, if you must spell it out, _the house where he and I live_. It is confusing to mention the word _house_ twice.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Should I say they is the same house in (1)?

Comment: _They is_ is ungrammatical. I have already suggested that you say _Our house is close to the school canteen_.

Comment: Further to @Kate Bunting's comment - which she should post as a perfectly good answer - you could also say "His and my house is close to the school."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Confusing and wrong. If you are sharing a house say "Our house is...". As there is one house it is confusing to refer to it as two things. Although this is sometimes done as trick (see below).
2. No. Two houses so use "are".  Better might be "Both our houses are ..."
3. Correct, two women

The trick question

> Elizabeth, Lizzy, Betsy, and Bess,
> They all went together to seek a bird's nest;
> They found a bird's nest with five eggs in,
> They all took one, and left four in.

If you are not playing such tricks, don't say "His house and my house".

Comment: Yes sentence 1 is wrong.  Indeed my answer states "1. is confusing and wrong"

Comment: Kate can write her own answer, but I think that "is" is correct if you change "His house and my house" to "our house".

Comment: It turns out Kate is right. https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.writersdigest.com/.amp/write-better-fiction/are-subjects-joined-by-and-singular-or-plural-grammar-rules

Comment: She is so smart. My grammar book is wrong.

Comment: That link doesn't apply to this context, which could only normally occur in trick questions like the Biden one.

Comment: “Sentence subjects that have multiple nouns connected by and that refer to a singular thing require singular verbs. Consider, Green eggs and ham was Sam-I-Am’s favorite dish.”

Comment: That's true, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: That’s also true.

Comment: For sentence 1 I would recommend "His and my house is..."